# redirect from one jsp to another jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, redirect, servlets

I have a question. I have to jsp files (index.jsp and neuesSpiel.jsp). When I click on a button in index.jsp I want to redirect to neuesSpiel.jsp

Here is some Code (index.jsp):

Button:

```
<input type="image" src="images/neuesSpiel.png" name="neuesSpiel"   height=50%  id="neuesSpiel" alt="neuesSpiel">
```

onclick function

```
$("#neuesSpiel").click(function() {
<%response.sendRedirect("neuesSpiel.jsp");%>});
```

But when I open up the index.jsp I will be automatically redirected to neuesSpiel.jsp. I only want to redirect when I click the button.
Whats wrong?

Comment: You're mixing JavaScript and Java/JSP scriptlets. The former is executed on the client, e.g. when the user clicks a button, while the latter is executed when _rendering_ the page, i.e. before the user sees it. But why don't you use a plain old link or a button?

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `Java` code as part of JavaScript. Following solve your problem.

```
$("#neuesSpiel").click(function() {
   window.location.href="neuesSpiel.jsp";
});
```

Also you can pass java variable to JavaScript. For Exmaple:

```
<%  
    String pageName = "neuesSpiel.jsp";  
%>
    <input type="button" value="redirect" onclick="redirectPage('<%=pageName%>')" />
```

Your javascript:

```
function redirectPage(pageName){
    window.location.href=pageName;
}
```

Comment: I tried this too, but then i stay on the index.jsp for some reason and the URL is: /bvsTest/index.jsp?neuesSpiel.x=403&neuesSpiel.y=177

Comment: I think there is no exception in my code. Please check your code with attention. If my answer helps you see following:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers